# Make CGRectMake Frame Stick to Bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to have a view that expands to fit the remaining height of the screen. The issue is that I am trying to do this on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 layouts.

What I would like to do is have my CGRectMake code so that the frame just anchors to the bottom of the main view. Is there a way to do something like this? Thanks!

Heres my webView CGRectMake code:

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 167, 320, 313);
```

Comment: Use auto layout. Or, if you really want to stick with manual frame calculations, look at CGRectDivide() and use the bounds of your view controller's view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use **auto layout** here to avoid hardcoding.

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addSubview:webView];

NSDictionary *viewsDict = @{@"webView" : webView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-167-[webView]-0-|" 
                  options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[webView]-0-|" 
                  options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
```

You will also avoid layout issues when performing **autorotating**

Answer (score 0):

You can make a reference to the views frame to accomplish this.

```
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 167, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 167);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a fixed starting height it's too easy:

```
int startHeight = 167;
int frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - startHeight;
webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, startHeight, 320, frameHeight);
```

What this does is to get the view's height, then it deducts the start offset of the Window.
For this to work, the code needs to be executed after the view has been displayed on the `UIWindow`, which means you need to execute it in `viewDidAppear` and not `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

If you give up on setting frame rects directly and embrace auto layout, this will be easy.